# How to add missing faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

Accidentally deleted 3 faces and didn't notice that. How should I properly restore it now?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a far more elegant way than this (I'm not that experienced with the mesh editing tools) but I would simply select that middle edge and <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude that down to reform that middle face. Then simply select each set of 4 vertices, hitting <kbd>F</kbd> to create each of the side faces.